# Converting latitude and longitude points to UK counties

Tags: software-recommendations, latitude-longitude, api, united-kingdom, county

I would like to find an API whereby I can send it (UK) lat and long pairs and it will return a UK county if one exists for that pair.

Ideally I will send it {50.3755,4.1427} and it will return {Devon}.

I understand that this isn't a coding or directly technical question but it seemed like the best place to ask with the breadth of experience.

Has anyone had this requirement before?

Comment: Thinking the OS SPARQL Linked Data API might be of use here (http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/) did you try already?

Comment: Nominatim API (OpenStreetMap) your lat/lng goes to the api http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=50.3755&lon=-4.1427&zoom=18&addressdetails=1 you get a response in xml.

Comment: Unfortunately that returned Plymouth as the county of Plymouth. What do you think could cause that? That lat,long is a minimum of 1 mile from the county boundary if that's an issue.

Comment: I haven't tried the OS API - do you know if it'll take a lat long? I couldn't see anything in the documentation.

Comment: Which OS API? It is fairly straighforward to convert OSGB to lat/long.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an API or existing service but it would be trivially easy to build one with [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) and [OS BoundaryLine data](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/boundary-line.html) bearing in mind that much of Britain isn't in a county.

Just load the data into the GeoServer.

[image]

Then make a GetFeature request against it using something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&version=1.0.0&typeName=topp:county_region&outputFormat=GML2&FILTER=%3CFilter%20xmlns=%22http://www.opengis.net/ogc%22%20xmlns:gml=%22http://www.opengis.net/gml%22%3E%3CIntersects%3E%3CPropertyName%3Ethe_geom%3C/PropertyName%3E%3Cgml:Point%20srsName=%22EPSG:4326%22%3E%3Cgml:coordinates%3E0,51%3C/gml:coordinates%3E%3C/gml:Point%3E%3C/Intersects%3E%3C/Filter%3E
```

And you could even change the return type to json and get:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":1,"features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"county_region.6","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":...},{"geometry_name":"the_geom","properties":{"NAME":"East Sussex County","AREA_CODE":"CTY","DESCRIPTIO":"County","FILE_NAME":"EAST_SUSSEX_COUNTY","NUMBER":16,"NUMBER0":502,"POLYGON_ID":122242,"UNIT_ID":2625,"CODE":"E10000011","HECTARES":172516.861,"AREA":1247.727,"TYPE_CODE":"AA","DESCRIPT0":"CIVIL ADMINISTRATION AREA","TYPE_COD0":"","DESCRIPT1":""}}],"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700"}}}
```

Comment: I'd be really happy to get to the 83 metro/non-metro counties. Thanks for your guidance, I'll look into this.

Comment: I think they are a different layer in boundaryline though still just GB not UK